# NAudio - Create software beat machine / sampler - General Strategy

Tags: naudio

Im new to NAudio but the goal of my project is to provide the user with the ability for the user to listen to an MP3 and then select a sample or a "chunk" of that song as a sample which could be saved to disk. These samples would be able to replayed at the same time (i.e. not merged but played at the same time).

Could someone please let me know what the overall strategy required to achieve this (....not necessarily the specifics...almost like pseduo code....).

For example would the samples / chunks of a song need to be saved as a WAV file. And these samples could be played together in the WAV format, etc.

I have seen a few small examples of a few implementations of some of the ideas Ive mentioned above but dont have a good sense of the big picture just yet.

Thanks in advance, 
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

The chunks wouldn't need to be saved as WAV files unless you were keeping them for future use. You can store the PCM audio (`Mp3FileReader` automatically converts to PCM) in a byte array and use `RawSourceWaveStream` to play them.

As for mixing them, I'd recommend using the `MixingSampleProvider`. This does mean you need to convert your `RawSourceWaveStream` to IEEE float, but you can use `Pcm16BitToSampleProvider` to do this. This will give the advantage that you can adjust volumes (and do other DSP) easily on the samples you are mixing. `MixingSampleProvider` also auto-removes completed inputs, so you can just add new inputs whenever you want to trigger a sound.